# How can I avoid this InvalidCastException?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an extension method that I've used for years in WinForms, but not since I've tried to use it in a new WPF project.  The method:

```
public static String GetDescription(this Enum value)
{
    //var info = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    //if (info != null)
    //{
    //    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    //    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
    //        return attributes[0].Description;
    //}
    //return value.ToString();

    var info = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    var attributes = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(info);
    if (attributes.Length > 0 && (attributes[0] is System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute))
        return ((System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;
    return value.ToString();
}
```

The first chunk (that is commented out) is the original method.  The second chunk is a slightly different version of it that I've been testing with.  If I force the return line with the cast to execute, I get this exception:

[image: InvalidCastException image]

The full text of the exception from that dialog is:

> Additional information: [A]System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute cannot be cast to [B]System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute. Type A originates from 'System.ComponentModel.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\TFS_Local\Antero\AnteroWPF\bin\Debug\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll'. Type B originates from 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'.

The two assemblies involved seem to be:

`System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll` (exists in the build bin directory...not entirely sure how it got there)

`System.dll` (referenced directly from GAC, for obvious reasons)

I'm completely lost here.  If I remove the ComponentModel DLL, that becomes the exception.  Even though the exception claims that `System` has the type, no use of it seems possible.  I.e. `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute` does not seem to be a valid thing to do in the absence of the corresponding DLL.

So, if I remove one and that fails, and the other is complete unusable...then why is this exception even occurring?!

**EDIT:**
I think it's worth nothing that if I inspect the value of `attributes` in memory, I see that the array does have a single item and it is of type `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute`.

Comment: The line with the cast

Comment: It works fine for me: https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/commit/c80e3e9828cb08c11cd17031fa10e6a4852878da#diff-225b67798e354b1ad8b608f72aa1ded5

Comment: @HelderSepu While your example is actually incomplete (your enum values do not have description attributes), it does incidentally work in that simplistic form.  Unfortunately, that does not make the difference clear to me.

Comment: @DonBoitnott can you provide a complete example

Comment: Here I started one for you: http://rextester.com/TYUY61604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I remove the ComponentModel DLL, that becomes the exception

*What* becomes the exception?

The exception you're getting is 100% clear: two different assemblies that your project is referencing define the same type, `System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute`. This type [is documented as being defined in **System.dll**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). So the **System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll** assembly seems to be the suspect one.

A little web searching leads me to this [System.ComponentModel.Primitives NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ComponentModel.Primitives/4.3.0). From this description, this appears to be related to .NET Core, and indeed, there is an [implementation of that type in the .NET Core source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Primitives/src/System/ComponentModel/DescriptionAttribute.cs).

At compile time, the assembly appears to have been placed in your build directory, `C:\TFS_Local\Antero\AnteroWPF\bin\Debug`. So, the question is, if you're building a WPF program, why do you have a .NET Core assembly in the build directory? Did you install the NuGet package at some point? Your build directory includes the root `TFS_Local`, which hints that you may be enlisted in a Team Foundation Server repository. Is it possible a co-worker installed the package for your build?

I haven't seen anything that would lead me to believe that you can mix-and-match the desktop .NET Framework with .NET Core. So the short answer seems to me to simply be "don't do that". You may get some *other* error without the **System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll** assembly referenced, but you will need to address those some other way. I'm not aware of any reason to believe you should expect to be able to compile a desktop WPF program using .NET Core DLLs.

If you believe otherwise, it would be helpful if you would explain why you think you can use a .NET Core assembly in your WPF program, how exactly you are doing that, and what steps you've taken to ensure that types declared in .NET Core don't conflict with types declared in the desktop .NET Framework assemblies, including **System.dll**.

Comment: In the end, your speculation that another team member had contributed the change is on the right track.  The assembly that provides the enum was made "portable" to work with a mobile project, and that caused the primitives DLL to be sucked in, leading to the exception (and my confusion about how it got there).

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, empty your bin and obj folders. Set copy local to false on your references from the GAC.